# get_member always returns None (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to 'fetch' member object from user id as an int. I have all Privileged Gateway Intents turned on in Dev portal. Even when I pull my actual member object ,using message.author,and put my id in it still returns none.

My Code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
    
    
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='c!', intents=intents)

## Skip some lines

   if message.content.startswith('c! null'):
      user = message.author
      copy=message.content
      testid=int(copy[8:])
      testid2= user.id
      print(testid)
      testing=message.guild.get_member(testid)
      testing2=message.guild.get_member(int(testid2))
      testing3= bot.get_user(testid)
      testing4=message.guild.fetch_member(int(testid2))
      guild=message.guild
      print(user)
      print(testing)
      print(testing2)
      print(testing3)
      print(guild)
      print(testing4)
```

My output:

```
93107305319538088
FakeUser#6969
None
None
None
MockServer
<coroutine object Guild.fetch_member at 0x7fc884680e40>


coroutine 'Guild.fetch_member' was never awaited
  await coro(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have all Privileged Gateway Intents turned on in Dev portal.

Unfortunately, **this does nothing** because your bot needs to enable those intents inside itself as well.

You have to enable the intents in the bot. When you use [`discord.Intents.default()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.default), you are disabling them in the bot - and as such, you won't get them.

You need to enable the specific intents you're using.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
#intents.presences = True
#intents.message_content = True
```

---

Note that this can still fail. [`get_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member) can sometimes fail if the member is not in the bot's cache, though this is unlikely.

So yes, you can use fetch, but it is an API call, so instead of doing `testing4=message.guild.fetch_member(int(testid2))` you need `testing4 = await message.guild.fetch_member(int(testid2))`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had it set that way and it wouldn't work, then I changed it to intents.all (which you can't give a true value from what it's was telling)

Comment: As a side note: this is on a client event on message, idk if that makes a difference

Comment: Also,  how does cache work? Why would a user be or not be in the cache

Comment: The code you sent is `intents = discord.Intents.default()`. Cache is just the bot keeping its own list of user ids and whatever to speed things up. It's generally automatic and every user that's in a guild that you are also in *should* be in cache. What is your discordpy version? Does using fetch (with `await`) work?

Comment: I'm away from home for a get hours, I'll update the code when I get back

Comment: I have edited my current intents in the original question to reflect new changes, however all lines still provide None except the fetch ( now that I added await).

Comment: What is your discordpy version? Also, try adding print statement to see what `testid` is. What happens if you do `<@IDGOESHERE>`?

Comment: discord.py 1.7.3 , and testid comes back as whatever is typed after the command

Comment: So fetching works and getting doesn’t? This probably means the cache is messed up or too small. You can check if get is None, and if it is, use fetch